# Jest tests not seeing the test files in "Vanilla Static" template

Tags: codesandbox

I haven't successfully used jest tests in codesandbox before, but I heard it was zero config. I am trying now in this "Vanilla Static" template:

https://codesandbox.io/s/lr74k637mq

I created a PathStore.test.js - however the test console is never picking it up. Is there some configuration I have to do?

I thought to add "jest" as a dependency, so I did that, but its still not working.

Comment: Something weird. In my console I can see `GET https://bundlephobia.com/api/size?package=jest@24.1.0 500`. You might need to reach out to codesandbox team.

Comment: Thanks @AnthonyKong for this, I'm still stuck on it!

Comment: @Noitidart Did you ever raise an issue with the CodeSandbox team? I'm running into this problem right now!

Comment: @SheaBelsky I never raised it, :( please let me know how you fix

Comment: We got the issue resolved, and there is a small amount of config needed on CodeSandbox (you have to add Jest as a dependency for it to work)

Comment: Thanks @SheaBelsky! Can you please answer this question and I'll upvote it!